# SQL merging cells

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have this tables:
T:

[image]

D:

[image]

What I am trying to do is to get for each `s_id` all it's symbols (`DBSymbol`) in one cell (merge cells).

I have found [this](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2914/rolling-up-multiple-rows-into-a-single-row-and-column-for-sql-server-data/) tutorial, and here is my code:

```
select T.s_id, 
    (select '; ' + D.symbol 
     from D 
     where T.D_b_id = D.id 
     FOR XML PATH('')) [DBSymbol]
from T
```

but here is what I am getting:

[image]

What is wrong??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this -

```
SELECT t1.s_id,
       STUFF(
           (SELECT '; ' + symbol AS [text()]
               FROM   (
                      SELECT t.s_id,
                             d.symbol
                      FROM   T
                      INNER JOIN D ON  T.d_b_id = D.id
                      WHERE t.s_id = t1.s_id                      
                      ) x
            FOR XML PATH('')
           ), 1, 1, '')
FROM T t1
GROUP BY t1.s_id
```

Check it: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/997bf/2/0)

Comment: In the code above there are syntax errors, in the inner query `t` table is not defined.

Comment: after some syntax changes it solved my problem, don't know about the performance of this. Thanks:)

Comment: Syntax error? t is defined in `FROM   T` clause. It's not case sensitive. There is working demo in sql fiddle.

Answer (score 1):

```
select DISTINCT T.s_id, 
Stuff((SELECT DISTINCT  '; ' + D.symbol 
     from  D 
     --where T.D_b_id = D.id 
     FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'') [DBSymbol]
from T
```

Example [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/217d6/5)

Comment: where to put the Stuff closing `)` ?

Comment: I am getting same result but without the `;` at the beginning of each symbol :(

Comment: Sorry, now I am getting this rows: `3, O;S` , `3, O;S` , `4, O;S`

Comment: In the example it is the same result as described in the above comment